# Performing perspective transform without corner points

Tags: iphone, ios, image, image-processing

I have a picture of a graph on a piece of paper that has no bounding box.  I need to transform the image such that it appears to have been taken from directly above.  Is it possible to do this without the corner points?

Here's an image to illustrate what im trying to accomplish:

[image]

P1-P5 are known, while A-D are unknown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 4 source points (midpoints at left picture) and 4 corresponding destination points at right pictures. You have enough information to calculate matrix of perspective transformation:

[Theory article](http://graphics.cs.cmu.edu/courses/15-463/2008_fall/Papers/proj.pdf)

[Example](http://xenia.media.mit.edu/~cwren/interpolator/) (dead link)

Comment: Example link is broken

Comment: @Tom It's sad - that article was very informative. Added theory.

Answer (score 0):

This is a 2D digital picture of a 2D piece of picture, shot at an angle?

If so, you don't have a 3D object, you have a distorted picture, and you need to correct for the distortion. A keystone correction should work. If the graph has graph lines on it you can measure the amount that the lines angle in to the back, and figure out how much to stretch the back of the image to correct for the keystone distortion.

Keystone correction is not something I've done before with transformation matrixes, but I know it's possible.